# JSP doesn't detect controller variables

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to clean up and migrate a Spring MVC application using XML configuration to Java code configuration. Everything went well except for variables being sent from the controller. When I try to access a variable from the model map in my JSP-view, the variable name with the dollar sign and curly braces gets printed instead of the variable value. I.e. a model map variable called, say **error**, appears as **${error}** in the pages.

Can someone shade lights on this please?

Comment: Which app-server do you use? Tomcat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spring, but that `Expression Language` (`EL`) is disabled for you. There may be several reasons for this, depending upon the Servlet container you are using. One reason may be that you're using an old XML namespace declaration in your web.xml file.

You can always force EL to be evaluated in a JSP by adding `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` on the top of the jsp page.

Comment: Splendid. I just changed changed the namespace declaration of my web.xml and it works fine now. One thing though, is the web.xml not ignored when you use java config??

Comment: Nope, you can still have a web.xml and use Spring Java config. You may convert your web.xml java code as well, but that's not the same as Spring Java Config.

Comment: I changed my web.xml to version 2.5 to resolve this same issue:  `<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">`